# total vertices without edges C

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

So I'am studying for my exam, and found the following question which i couldn't understood how to solve it:

The Graph:

```
        typedef struct NODE{
             int weight;
             int idEdge;
             int idDestination;
             struct NODO *next;
        }Node;
```

And following this prototype:

```
    int totVertexWithoutEdges(Node **g, int totv)
```

I must create the function that gives me the total number of vertex without edges but I have no ideia how to do it, can anyone just explain me how should I solve it, not asking for the answer just some steps to reach it.

Comment: Your struct is called `NODE`, but it seems to represent an edge (since it specifies the source and destination).  Is that intentional?

Comment: not sure, this is the way my teacher wrote it in the exame

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create an array with one entry per node.  Initially, set all the elements in this array to 0.

Then, iterate across all of the edges.  For each edge, change the array element representing the array element corresponding to the source node (and/or destination node, depending on how you interpret the problem) to 1.  This marks that the node has an edge connected to it.

Finally, iterate across the array and count up the number of 0 entries, which tells you the total number of nodes with no incoming/outgoing edges.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your totVertexWithoutEdges will just have to browse your Node** g, which will be the address of a pointer to a linked list.

Maybe something like(based on the fact that the last element points to NULL)

```
while (*g != NULL)
{
     // Check out what you want about your edge things
     g = &(*g)->next;
}
```

but if totv represents the number of vertices, it would be

```
int   counter;

counter = 0;
while (counter < totv)
{
     // Check out what you want about your edge things
     g = &(*g)->next;
     counter = counter + 1;
}
```

A linked list is a well-known data structure ;), good luck with your exercise.